# Apache ReverseProxy: handle SSLCertificateFile on proxy and SSLCACertificateFile on proxyed host

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, reverse-proxy, authentication

I've configured a Reverse Proxy with Apache, that proxy request to Tomcat Servers.

I've not found if it is possible to handle SSLCertificateFile on proxy itself  (in order to avoid the configuration of certificate on each internal server) and instead configure SSLCACertificateFile on each proxied server, configuring the proxy to forward Client Certificate handling to the specific server.

Does someone have some tips for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. The handshake is a unitary thing. You are terminating SSL at the HTTPD, which means it has to both provide its own certificate and CA certificate. What you are asking doesn't make sense.